# Google Analytics question, how do I know the number of my own visits?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a web app that I deployed in AppHarbor with Google Analytics. Development is still ongoing and I test it very often live to checkout for example stuffs I did with the CSS, etc.

Everything is working fine but I'd like to know how many times I am accessing the website apart from the rest of the visitors who visits it. When checking the reports in Google Analytics it only shows me the ISPs of the visitors. I'll need something more drilled down like an IP address, but this seems to go against Google Analytic's policy and I do not know if this is even possible still.

Like right now I have 72 visits. But I have been testing so a lot of those could just be me. Would be good to know the actual visitor count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is probably a little late but you can set a filter to ingore your own traffic from reports. [Here](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55481) is how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition for adding a deprecated variable and using filters, you can build the code so that it only prints the tracking code if e.g. an identifier cookie is not found. Other common option is a URL parameter.

You can then set this cookie for your browser and be excluded from traffic.